# Flutter - dynamically change container color

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, containers

I have an issue with my flutter application.
In my drawer I have created a toggle button to switch between light and dark styles.

Now this works for the most part, however the issue is that it seems that I can not dynamically change the color of drawer container color.

Can I get some assistance please, this is driving me nuts?

This code does not work - `style: Theme.of(context).CustomColors().fusaBlue,`

```
- theme_switch_widget.dart -
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import 'theme_switch_state.dart';
    
    class ThemeSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
      
      @override
      ThemeSwitchState createState() => new ThemeSwitchState();
    }

    - theme_switch_state.dart -
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import '../../themes/global/themes.dart';
    import 'themes_custom.dart';
    
    class ThemeSwitchState extends State {
      bool switchControl = false;
      //var textHolder = 'Theme is Light';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Transform.scale(
              scale: 1.5,
              child: Switch(
                onChanged: toggleSwitch,
                value: switchControl,
                activeColor: CustomColors().skyBlue,
                activeTrackColor: CustomColors().goreBlue,
                inactiveThumbColor: CustomColors().loreGrey,
                inactiveTrackColor: CustomColors().noroGrey,
              )),
          /*Text(
            '$textHolder',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
          )*/
        ]);
      }
    
      void _changeTheme(BuildContext buildContext, MyThemeKeys key) {
        CustomTheme.instanceOf(buildContext).changeTheme(key);
      }
    
      void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
        if (switchControl == false) {
          setState(() {
            switchControl = true;
            //textHolder = 'Theme is Dark';
          });
          print('Theme is Dark');
    
          // Put your code here which you want to execute on Switch ON event.
          _changeTheme(context, MyThemeKeys.DARK);
    
        } else {
          setState(() {
            switchControl = false;
            //textHolder = 'Theme is Light';
          });
          print('Theme is Light');
    
          // Put your code here which you want to execute on Switch OFF event.
          _changeTheme(context, MyThemeKeys.LIGHT);
        }
      }
    }

    - themes_custom.dart -
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import './themes.dart';

class _ThemesCustom extends InheritedWidget {
  final CustomThemeState data;

  _ThemesCustom({
    this.data,
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_ThemesCustom oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}

class CustomTheme extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final MyThemeKeys initialThemeKey;

  const CustomTheme({
    Key key,
    this.initialThemeKey,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CustomThemeState createState() => new CustomThemeState();

  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
    _ThemesCustom inherited =
        (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ThemesCustom>());
    return inherited.data.theme;
  }

  static CustomThemeState instanceOf(BuildContext context) {
    _ThemesCustom inherited =
        (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ThemesCustom>());
    return inherited.data;
  }
}

class CustomThemeState extends State<CustomTheme> {
  ThemeData _theme;

  ThemeData get theme => _theme;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _theme = MyThemes.getThemeFromKey(widget.initialThemeKey);
    super.initState();
  }

  void changeTheme(MyThemeKeys themeKey) {
    setState(() {
      _theme = MyThemes.getThemeFromKey(themeKey);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _ThemesCustom(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

- themes.dart -
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum MyThemeKeys {
  LIGHT,
  DARK,
}

class CustomColors {
  final novaWhite = Color(0xffecf0f1);
  final loreGrey = Color(0xff6c7a84);
  final noroGrey = Color(0xff424b51);
  final skyBlue = Color(0xff1da1f2);
  final fusaBlue = Color(0xff053959);
  final goreBlue = Color(0xff032234);
  final limeGreen = Color(0xff3bd37b);
  final leafGreen = Color(0xff2ecc71);
  final sageGreen = Color(0xff208c4d);
}

class MyThemes {
  static TextTheme baseTextTheme(TextTheme base) {
    return base.copyWith(
      display4: base.display4.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
        fontSize: 112.0,
      ),
      display3: base.display3.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 56.0,
      ),
      display2: base.display2.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 45.0,
      ),
      display1: base.display1.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 34.0,
      ),
      headline: base.headline.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 24.0,
      ),
      title: base.title.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 20.0,
      ),
      subhead: base.subhead.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 16.0,
      ),
      body2: base.body2.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 14.0,
      ),
      body1: base.body1.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 14.0,
      ),
      caption: base.caption.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 12.0,
      ),
      button: base.button.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 14.0,
      ),
      subtitle: base.subtitle.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 14.0,
      ),
      overline: base.overline.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'Iceland',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 10.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: CustomColors().limeGreen,
    indicatorColor: CustomColors().loreGrey,
    accentColor: CustomColors().limeGreen,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: CustomColors().novaWhite,

    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      size: 30.0,
      color: CustomColors().noroGrey,
    ),
    dividerTheme: DividerThemeData(
      thickness: 0.5,
      indent: 16,
      endIndent: 16,
      color: CustomColors().limeGreen,
    ),
    buttonColor: CustomColors().novaWhite,
    backgroundColor: CustomColors().novaWhite,
  );

  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primaryColor: CustomColors().skyBlue,
    indicatorColor: CustomColors().loreGrey,
    accentColor: CustomColors().skyBlue,
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: CustomColors().novaWhite,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      size: 30.0,
      color: CustomColors().noroGrey,
    ),
    dividerTheme: DividerThemeData(
      thickness: 0.5,
      indent: 16,
      endIndent: 16,
      color: CustomColors().skyBlue,
    ),
    buttonColor: CustomColors().novaWhite,
    backgroundColor: CustomColors().novaWhite,

  );

  static ThemeData getThemeFromKey(MyThemeKeys themeKey) {
    switch (themeKey) {
      case MyThemeKeys.LIGHT:
        return lightTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme: baseTextTheme(lightTheme.textTheme),
        );
        break;
      case MyThemeKeys.DARK:
        return darkTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme: baseTextTheme(darkTheme.textTheme),
        );
        break;
      default:
        return lightTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme: baseTextTheme(lightTheme.textTheme),
        );
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Share the code only for the toggle how you change the theme so we can help you. In the mean time tapping into the whole class to pick a color isn't the best way to do it. You should create a static constants in your custom color class and pick only the constant to chose color.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so I am writing it as an answer.

1. Make sure you have StatefulWidget, and use setState() when changing the theme.
2. You can use a static variable to check if it is light or dark mode, and get the color accordingly. ( color: isDarkMode ?  Colors.black : Colors:white)
3. If you don't want to use that, please share the code of toggle button's onTap function as well as CustomColors() source code.

Comment: It is too much to share here - mederators will complaine. Do you have anywhere else for me to share ?

Comment: I believe you can edit your post, and add it there. There shouldn't be any limit for it. Just add it as a source code

Comment: I have added my code - Please check it.
It is all there.
Please help me understand how I can update the colors of my containers dynamically

Comment: What is your main function looking like? Do you ever call (use) CustomTheme class before using the ThemeSwitch widget? Some of the colors are the same for the light and dark theme, maybe you should try to have totally different colors for each theme and try again.

Comment: Also, to use a color from the themes, you should use Theme.of(context).
For example:
For Light - you have - accentColor: CustomColors().limeGreen,
For Dark - you have - accentColor: CustomColors().skyBlue,
To use this color within a widget you should use
Theme.of(context).accentColor

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of your Container, follow these easy steps:

1. Create Color variable `c`

```
Color c = const Color(0xFF42A5F5);
```

The code inside `Color(...)` determines the color. See [this link](http://%20https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html) for color codes.

Use this in if-else condition if you have any like for dark the container color you choose will be stored in `c` and for the light theme, a different color will be saved in `c`.

2. In `Container` color property just call like this:

```
color: c,
```